# Kotlin reflection for object class gives null

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm diving into reflection and I've met the following issue with this object class:

```
object Dict {

     fun getAll(): Map<String, List<String>> {
        return mapOf(
            "Mark" to listOf("Banana"),
            "John" to listOf("Strawbery", "Pie"),
            "Lily" to listOf("Apple", "Banana", "Pie"),
        )
    }
}
```

knowing the package canonical name of this class I can get this method:

```
val dictClass = Class.forName("com.example.util.Dict")
val getAllRelationsMethod = relationsClass.getMethod("getAll")
val peopleWithMeals = getAllRelationsMethod.invoke(null) // this line gives error
```

I got the following exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null receiver`

I'm passing the null into the `invoke()` method because it doesn't need a class instance to call (like static in java). Does the method call differs from Java here somehow? Didn't find a tip around the Internet so that's why I'm asking here. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly you have to change it like that ..

```
@JvmStatic
fun getAll(): Map<String, List<String>> {
    return mapOf(
        "Mark" to listOf("Banana"),
        "John" to listOf("Strawbery", "Pie"),
        "Lily" to listOf("Apple", "Banana", "Pie"),
    )
}
```

[JVMStatic](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html)

Comment: Wow, that works. I thought I need to use this annotation only if my code is supposed to work with some other java code... Thanks!

Comment: If I am correct, the part or reflection is java, so you want the method to be static in java that is why you need the annotation :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can access (and have control over) both, the caller, as also the target, you probably shouldn't use reflection. `@JvmStatic` is a solution to this, but only if you can alter the target class.

If you can't and still need reflection, the following may help you:

```
val dictClass = Class.forName("com.example.util.Dict")
val getAllRelationsMethod = relationsClass.getMethod("getAll")
val objectInstance = dictClass.getField("INSTANCE").get(null) // get value of static field INSTANCE (which every object has)
val peopleWithMeals = getAllRelationsMethod.invoke(objectInstance)
```

It first extracts the object's instance with which you can call the object functions.

If you know that the object is always `Dict` and you imported it appropriately, you can also just use the following to call a function of/on it:

```
val dictClass = Class.forName("com.example.util.Dict")
val getAllRelationsMethod = relationsClass.getMethod("getAll")
val peopleWithMeals = getAllRelationsMethod.invoke(Dict) // Dict is an object and here the actual instance is used...
```

If it isn't very generic what you want to do, then omit reflection. Maybe having appropriate interfaces may help you accomplish something similar instead of using reflection?

Comment: It is very generic indeed. But thanks for all the tips :)

Comment: if it is very generic, then `@JvmStatic` is probably no solution to it... and if it is, it is probably not that generic ;-)

Comment: How can you know that without knowing the context of the project? :D

Comment: experience (if you can set `@JvmStatic` everywhere, then you can also introduce an appropriate other structure) ... but as I do not know for sure I used "probably" ;-)

Comment: I assure you that the reflection is exactly what I need in my strict example. I just want to point that the question wasn't about if I should use the reflection or not but how to get the object function from it ;-)

Comment: I don't really mind, if you require it to be honest... ;-) most of time I saw it used, it wasn't necessary (with a bit of refactoring)... but if you really require it, I doubt that `@JvmStatic` is the solution to it ;-) (as that will force you to adapt each and every `object`, which defeats the purpose of having a generic solution ;-))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203192/discussion-between-shurrok-and-roland).

Comment: Experiencing something similar with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876094/null-pointer-unresolved-reference-issue-with-kotlin-object

Not sure if I can make the whole class @Static